# Domain of factorial expression in denominator

Tags: factorial

I am wondering what is domain of this expression:

$\dfrac1{(n+2)!}$

It seems for me like it has to be $\;n+2\geqslant0\;$ and then has to be $\;n\geqslant -2.$

But we can write the factorial expression like this: $(n+2)(n+1)!$

And now when we will install number $-2$ it will be: $\;0\cdot(-1)! = 0\;$ because everything multiplied by $0$ is $0.$ So in the interval can’t be the number $-2.$

Can someone help me if someone understand me what I mean?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $0!=1$. So we can write $ (n+2)!=(n+2)(n+1)!$ only if $n+2>0$

Comment: But if (n+2)! is same as (n+2)(n+1)! there must be same domain in both expressions. For (n+2)! it will be n+2 >= 0 and for (n+2)(n+1)! it will be just n+2>0 ?

Comment: ...$(n+2)!$ is the same as $(n+2)(n+1)!$ only if $n+2>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand :)